# Upload multiple image files in PHP

Tags: php, html, multiple-file-upload

I am currently trying to upload multiple image files but I have some errors encountered as below:

> Notice: Undefined index: productPic in
> D:\laragon\www\byte\add_product.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> D:\laragon\www\byte\add_product.php on line 25
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
> implements Countable in D:\laragon\www\byte\add_product.php on
> line 25

Below is the PHP code starting from line 25 to line 40:

```
$totalFile = count($_FILES['productPic']['name']);   //line 25
 
for($i=0; $i<$totalFile; $i++)
{
  //ensure the file path is exist
  if($_FILES['productPic']['tmp_name'][$i] != "")
  {
    // upload the file into the temp directory
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productPic']['tmp_name'][$i],$_FILES['productPic']['name'][$i]))
    {
      $upload = 1;
      $pic[$i] == $_FILES['productPic']['name'][$i];
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the partial HTML code:

```
<form class="w-100" name="addProductForm" method="POST" action="add_product.php">
    .
    .
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col form-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control py-1" name="productPic[]" accept="image/*" multiple required>
        </div>
    </div>
    .
    .
</form>
```

Comment: First off, make sure you have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in the form tag.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Then, `var_dump($_FILES)` will tell you how the array is structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code

(A) make sure you have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in the form tag

So the HTML should be like:

```
<form class="w-100" name="addProductForm" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="add_product.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col form-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control py-1" name="productPic[]" accept="image/*" multiple required>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

(B) The following line in your PHP is incorrect (you need a assignment operator, not a comparison operator):

```
$pic[$i] == $_FILES['productPic']['name'][$i];
```

should be

```
$pic[$i] = $_FILES['productPic']['name'][$i];
```

So the PHP should be like:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$totalFile = count($_FILES['productPic']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$totalFile; $i++) {
            // ensure the file path is exist
            if($_FILES['productPic']['tmp_name'][$i] != "") {
               if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productPic']['tmp_name'][$i],$_FILES['productPic']['name'][$i])){
                    $upload = 1;
                    $pic[$i] = $_FILES['productPic']['name'][$i];
                }
            }
}

var_dump($pic);
?>
```

Last but not least, make sure that the directory is `writable`, otherwise the upload will fail